# Agile QR-code for iOS app

Tags: ios, url, encoding, uri, qr-code

I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve these goals using only single QR-code:

1) If QR-code was scanned *in my app* - then app performs some action with contained information (identifier of some object as text built in QR-code);

2) If QR-code was scanned not in my app (some QR-code reader, whatever), but *my app is installed on the device* - then open my app automatically and perform some action with contained information;

3) If QR-code was scanned not in my app, and *my app is not installed on the device* - then redirect on app download page.

For 1st case it's obvious - I just want to put text "id-123" in the QR-code.

Then 2nd case - I think, I need something like URI scheme to automatically open my app from whatever QR scanning app with this text "id-123" as some kind of URI link parameter? Is it possible?

Then 3rd case - it gets even complicated, because I want to be able to change redirection from beta test version downloading (link to fabric beta) to AppStore app page in future without touching QR-code at all. First thought - it will be one link to my custom site maybe, where I'll be able to change second redirection (from beta to AppStore version) remotely on the site, so I won't have to touch physical QR-code. And also I want to determine if link was opened from iOS or Android (or WP) to redirect to properly download link. I believe I can achieve this using browser's user agent? Is it possible?

And the main question - I have to combine all these 3 cases into one QR-code. As I can see - it must be link to my site with id as its parameter. So for 1st case I'll just grab this param in my app. And this might work for 3rd case - my backend will just grab main link and ignore param. But how to achieve 2nd case covering if using link to my backend, not URI scheme? Or maybe there are some better strategies? Can't figure out some smart and elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: Just encode a universal link as a QR code - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: @Paulw11 I'll check it, but I need all these cases to be compatible with iOS 7+, so it seems to be only iOS 9+ feature